# JavaFX - Visual resize glitch when rendering large number of Texts

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Is there a way to eliminate this visual glitch when resizing a container with a significant number of Text components? What is causing it?

[image]

Code used:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ResizeTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();

        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                Text t = new Text("A");
                t.setY(i * 15);
                t.setX(j * 10);
                root.getChildren().add(t);
            }
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is being shown on a Linux Mint PC.

Comment: I believe this is not a Java problem, your Linux OS cant render/update the window fast enough. There are a lot of post on the web of people complaining about this kind of problems and all are caused more or less because of the GPU issues like drivers etc or the graphic framework that the OS use. Note : I have no problem running the above code on windows but I might test it on Ubuntu later.

Comment: Thanks for the test on Win - still, I hope to find a way to speed things up a bit to avoid this. I don't see this effect under normal circumstances, so it's probably something to do with work the Text component is doing... I think.

Comment: Nope, this has nothing to do with the text component specifically. Still seeing the issue with just a BorderPane and a few empty containers. Pretty annoying. Only mitigation seems to be setting a darker fill color on the scene so it doesn't flash bright white at you.